# Is it "slang English" or "English slang", or maybe both?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Given that **slang** is a noun, I guess being modified by **English** is almost equal to the other way round since a noun can modify another noun.

Answer (score 2):

Since slang words and phrases are very much country-dependent, it would be better to talk about British slang, American slang, etc. Also, the nationality is acting as an adjective, so it should come first.

Comment: I second this answer. You generally don't say '**English slang**'. Slang is associated to a locality. *'British slang'* is a perfect example.